why ref does not get value in conditional rendering
i have a component which renders conditionally and i pass a ref to it via forwardRef of React ,but when condition met and component renders, the ref still has not any value,
what should i do?
here is my simulated code
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Table from "./Table";

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setList(["faraz"]);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  console.log("ref************", ref);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {!!list.length && <Table ref={ref} />}
    </div>
  );
}

and my child and conditional rendered component
import React from "react";

const Table = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
      <div ref={ref}></div>
    </div>
  );
});
export default Table;


i try pass ref with forward ref to child component but ref never get a value, how can i set ref value on conditional rendered component

In your example ref actually does have a value, it is just not being logged.
To understand why, let's analyze step-by-step what is happening in the code you provided:
(first render)

state initialized: list = []; ref.current = null
console.log("ref************", ref); // logs: '{current: null}'
App renders
Because list.length === 0, Table doesn't render, so ref.current remains null
useEffect runs, triggers a state update (which queues a new render)

(second render)

new state: list = ["faraz"]; ref.current = null
console.log("ref************", ref); // logs: '{current: null}'
App re-renders
Because list.length === 1, Table renders as well and sets ref.current = {current: HTMLDivElement {...}}
Since ref updates do not trigger new renders and there are no new state updates, App doesn't re-render and your console.log doesn't get a chance to log the new ref.current value.

To verify your ref.current value is actually set, you can update the code to render Table no matter the list length, which will set ref.current on first render, thus causing the console.log during the second render to log its value.
You can find the code with described update here https://playcode.io/1863189

@faraz it's not ok to ask questions and then ignore responses. I took time out of my day because I really wanted to help you out, and the least you can do is leave some feedback to say if the answer was helpful or not.
